# How do I make a custom success page from HTML insert form?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that inserts a record into MySQL via HTML form. How do I make it go to the HTML page after submission and create a popup of success or a popup of failure?

```
$host="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$username="XXXXXXXXXXX";
$password="XXXXXXXXXXX";
$db_name="naturan8_hero";
$tbl_name="cartons_current";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$order = "INSERT INTO cartons_current (type, part_no, description, count, size, min, max, qty) VALUES('$_POST[type]', '$_POST[part_no]', '$_POST[description]', '$_POST[count]', '$_POST[size]', '$_POST[min]', '$_POST[max]', '$_POST[qty]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if ($result) {
  echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
}
else {
  echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
```

Comment: It means you have to wait two days, before to offer a bounty on this question.

Comment: [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) there and you can use `header("Location: page.php?msg=success_or_fail_here")` to send to another page, more php docs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should really add some security to your script as `$_POST` may contain SQL Injections.

try to trim all your post fields and add [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);
// ......... etc ..
```

the second part, the answer to your question, I believe you should set a `$_SESSION` variable:

start of the file:

```
session_start();
```

after your query:

```
if ($result) {
   $_SESSION['result'] = 'success';
} else {
   $_SESSION['result'] = 'fail';
}
// and redirect to your page
header('Location http://www.example.org/result.php');
exit;
```

on your html `result.php` add the same `session_start()` and check for `$_SESSION['result']` variable, then you add some javascript for the popup, of course you can do some [modal window](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) or your could just echo an message.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['result']) && ($_SESSION['result'] != '')){
    if($_SESSION['result'] == 'success'){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open ('http://www.example.org/result-ok.php','success');"; // result-ok.php
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open ('http://www.example.org/result-notok.php','fail');"; // result-notok.php
    }
}
```

in both of that files you unset that session variable to prevent that window open again:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['result']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent on this.  I am very grateful.